# Wi-fi speeds vary enormously between devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mac, fios

I have Verizon FIOS 1 gig internet. On my Mac mini using a wired Ethernet (CAT-6) connection, speed tests (OOKLA and one other) typically show 700 Mbps +/- 50. However on three different Apple devices (iPhone 10, 12, iPad Pro 2021) speeds are consistently and dramatically less, about 35Mbps +/- 10.

Here’s the kicker. When I switch to wireless (WiFi) on the Mac Mini, the speed actually increases to about 800! The phones were checked in the same room as the mini, BTW.

Router is part of the home automation system, which uses high-grade equipment. I can get specific brand and model number if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the slow devices *capable* of faster speeds? On any other WiFi network, have you ever observed faster throughput with them?

Comment: Can you provide the version of WIFI these devices are using?  You don't specify anything that could identify the Mac Mini

Comment: An iPhone 12 supports WiFi 6 (ax) with 2 spatial streams. The question is—what does your access point support? Are they even using a 5 GHz network?

Comment: At first blush it sounds like you've accidentally got the iPhones/iPad joining the 2.4GHz band instead of the much faster 5GHz band. And yes, please edit your question to provide the exact make/model of your APs (wireless routers). The Wi-Fi specifications of your APs matters a great deal. It's almost never worth asking a Wi-Fi performance question without documenting the Wi-Fi specs of the Wi-Fi gear involved (APs and client devices), or at least documenting the exact makes/models so we can look up the specs for ourselves.